# Cakephp reverse routing : prevent fallback

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, url-routing

In cakephp (branch 2.5), when trying to build an url from an array, cakephp will make up one if it does not find a matching one in Config/routes.php.

Maybe an example will be more useful :)

When I do this :

```
echo Router::url(array(
    'controller'       => 'some_non_existing_controller',
    'action'           => 'some_non_existing_action',
    'fake_named_param' => 'blahblah'
));
```

I get that :

```
/some_non_existing_controller/some_non_existing_action/fake_named_param:blahblah
```

What I would like to get is an exception telling me "hey, this route does not exist". This would help me debugging my work, and let me know immediately when I break links when changing things in Config/routes.php.

When digging into cakephp core code, i found the responsible for this behaviour. It is located exactly here => http://api.cakephp.org/2.5/source-class-Router.html#921-921

But since I don't want to mess with core code, i'd like to know if anybody had an idea of how to do this properly?

Thanks !

Comment: Even if you do something like that i think it will need much time to check all your application to see if the url exists. Probably you might need to check the url only at certain debug modes.

Comment: The app is actually already in production. The idea would be to log the exception thrown by a wrong reverse routing. This is not ideal, but right now, when there is a broken link, it can remains for month before i see it!

Comment: Why wouldn't you use one of link checker tools instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested Deimoks, I had a look at the custom Route class. First I didn't think it could resolve my problem because in cakephp custom Route class aims at defining how to parse an url to a routing array or how to convert a routing array to an url, **for a given route**. Yet my problem is precisely how cakephp handles reverse routing when there is no matching route.

So the idea was to create a new route **at the end** of Config/routes.php whose goal is only to catch reverse routing attempts that were not resolved before. If this route is solicited for reverse-routing it means something is wrong with the routing array because none of the other routes found an url for it.
This route is then handled by a custom route class that will log the reverse routing failure.

**At the end** of Config/routes.php :

```
App::uses('GarbageRoute', 'Routing/Route');
Router::connect('/', array(), array('routeClass' => 'GarbageRoute'));
```

In /Routing/Route/GarbageRoute.php :

```
<?php

class GarbageRoute extends CakeRoute {

    public function match($url)
    {
        trigger_error(print_r($url, true) . 'does not match any url', E_USER_NOTICE);
        return false;
    }
}
```

I'm still surprised cakephp does not support it natively and that I had to create custom classes to get this behavior. If anybody has a better solution, feel free to share!

Answer (score 0):

Just delete this line from your `routes.php`.

```
require CAKE . 'Config' . DS . 'routes.php';
```

Now only explicitly connected routes will work.

Comment: This line is already deleted in my Config/routes.php file. As far as I understand, deleting this line prevents default cakephp routing (i.e linking an url to an array of controller / action / params), but it doesn't prevent default **reverse**-routing (i.e linking an array of controller / action / params to an url).

Comment: @PGBI Then you need a custom Route class. Check the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#custom-route-classes) about this as well as [this post by Mark Story](http://mark-story.com/posts/view/using-custom-route-classes-in-cakephp).